# Does a WatchKit app require a separate provisioning profile from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, bundle-identifier

I am getting ready to upload my app to the app store. My app has a WatchKit app as well, and I am just wondering if I need a separate bundle identifier for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is usually automatically created by Xcode.  It should be your iOS app, plus ".watchkitapp" (i.e. If your iOS app is com.mydomain.www, then  com.mydomain.www.watchkitapp) You'll also need one for the extension, it's iOS app plus ".watchkitextension" (i.e. com.mydomain.www.watchkitextension). Both app and extension have their own info.plists.

Comment: Hmm....your title asks a different question, then your question does.  In answer to your title, you need separate provisioning profiles for your iOS app, your extension and your watch app, three in all.

Comment: Your answer helped. Thanks!